# Mouseout function is being called while I'm still hovering over my mouseover object

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps api I'm calling a mouseout command with the addDomListener like so:

```
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById(#myID), 'mouseout', mouseoutListener);
```

myID is a div, with some child elements, e.g.

```
<div id="myID">
  <title>etc</title>
  <address>etc</title>
</div>
```

The mouseout works when leaving #myID, but the problem is that *it also triggers when hovering over the children elements*. I understand jQuery solved this by making mouseenter and mouseleave triggers, but those aren't available (to my knowledge) in this API unfortunately.

How is this accomplished?

In other words, how do you getElementById AND so that this covers all of the child elements?

Answer (score 0):

You may use mouseleave and mouseenter also with addDomListener, the problem is that these events are not supported by all major browsers(they should work in IE, FF and Opera, but fail in Chrome and Safari).

You may use another library like e.g. jQuery which has a cross-browser-implementation for these events.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. Is it possible to use jQuery's functions inside google's addDomListener event though? My understanding is that it would only accept simple strings like 'mouseout' 'mouseover' etc

Comment: no, you can use jquery's event-functions directly, addDomListener is only a wrapper like jQuery's methods.

Comment: I have been trying for a while to see how I could have say $('#object-a').hover() do something to marker[0], but as yet I can't work out how that is done.

Comment: There is no code example that goes along your proposal

Comment: @singe32: code-example for what? Replacing a string `mouseout` in an existing example with the string `mouseleave`?